# how can I write rows from mysql to logfile in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

How can I write the rows of a mysql select to a logfile so every row is on a newline and all columns are split by "|"?

I'm using python3.

EDIT:

I see I have given a bit to little info, sorry.

What I have is this:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM `table1` where date < x'

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
filename = '/logs/data.log'
fp = open(filename, 'w', newline='\n')
myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator='\n')
myFile.writerows(rows)
```

However this is comma seperated and it can happen that there are comma's in the datafields and all rows are appended after another instead of on a newline.

And would it be possible to directly tar the file which is created?

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote to attempt to solve this problem and describe what specifically is not working the way you expect or want?

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you queried the database and gotten the results?  Have you looped over the results?  Do you know about [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)?

Comment: @takendarkk I edited my question, I do have good results from the query

Comment: @RocketHazmat I edited my question

Comment: Besides `lineterminator`, csv.writer has `delimiter` and `quotechar`.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden thanks for the delimiter that solves the "|" but how can I write every row to a newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch of what I think you need:

```
import csv
rows = cursor.fetchall()
filename = '/logs/data.log'
fp = open(filename, 'w')  #  newline='\n' not needed

w = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator='\n', delimiter='|', quotechar='')
w.writerows(rows)
```

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples.  The `csv.writer` documentation doesn't say, but I expect is takes any sequence of sequences.

Comment: It gives an error with the empty quotechar but without quotechar it works. I viewed the file in notepad which didn't show the rows on a newline but in nano it does. thanks. Do you happen to know how I can tar it directly?